# How to filter the list of objects in the list without changing the original list

Tags: java, java-stream

The simplified code structure looks like this:

```
public class A {
   private List<B> bList;
}

public class B {
   private A a;
   private List<C> cList;
}

public class C {
   private B b;
   private String name;
}
```

I would like to filter the list of objects A in such a way that they contain only those objects C with the name "123".

I don't want to change the original list.
I can use this code:

```
List<A> orginalList;
orginalList.stream()
            .flatMap(a -> a.getBlist().stream())
            .flatMap(b -> b.getClist().stream())
            .filter(c -> "123".equals(c.getName()))
            .collect(toList());
```

But this code will only return me a filtered list of C objects.
I want to get a list of objects A containing a list of objects B, which contains a list of objects C only having name = "123".

For example, I have something like that:

```
[
   {
    "bList": [
        {
            "cList": [
                {
                    "name": "123"
                },
                {
                    "name": "555"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

]

I want to get:

```
 [
   {
    "bList": [
        {
            "cList": [
                {
                    "name": "123"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Comment: Do you mean that all `C.name` must be `"123"`? Or do you mean `A` objects with at least one `C` object with `"123"` as name?

Comment: @ernest_k 
I just want to filter cList, not originalist. I want to get a cList containing only c.name = "123".
If cList has two objects - with the name "123" and "555", I want to get a list of objects A, containing a list of B objects that have the cList only with C with the name "123".

Comment: You probably need to make copy constructors for your objects and filter the list into your new `B` objects

Comment: you can do this: `List<A> result = new ArrayList<>();
        orginalList.forEach(a -> {
            A a1 = new A(new ArrayList<>());
            a.getBList().forEach(b -> {
                B b1 = new B(new ArrayList<>());
                b.getCList().stream().filter(c -> c.getName().equals("123")).forEach(c -> b1.getCList().add(c));
                a1.getBList().add(b1);
            });
            result.add(a1);
        });`

Comment: It seems that a `new A(new ArrayList<>())` is always added to the `result`, regardless of whether it meets the "123"-criteria or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the first element then filter by the first collection then using anyMatch to validate if the inner collection have something you need.

```
List<A> orginalList;
orginalList.stream()
            .filter(a -> a.getBlist().stream()
                  .anyMatch(b -> b.getClist().stream()
                        .anyMatch(c -> "123".equals(c.getName())) )
            .collect(toList());
```

I think this example could be useful to get an idea.

Hope that this will be useful for you!

Answer (score 0):

The method `Stream::flatMap` flattens the structure which means the hierarchy is destroyed.

Here is a way to go:

```
List<A> filteredList = orginalList.stream()
    .filter(a -> a.getBlist()                   // filter the top List, where the List<B>
            .anyMatch(b -> b.getClist()         // .. has List<C>, where any C
                    .stream()                 
                    .map(C::getName)            // .... has a name
                    .anyMatch("123"::equals)))) // .... is equal to "123"
    .collect(Collectors.toList());              // collect to List
```

Comment: @I'mNoBody: Usually yes. For the SO answers, the easier ones I write from head and otherwise I run it by myself - I don't need them for the temporary solution for sake of answers.

Comment: @Nikolas This filters orignalList, not cList.

Answer (score 0):

*This preserves the whole path*

```
Map<Object, List<A>> map = originalList.stream().collect( groupingBy( a -> a.getBList().stream()
    .collect( groupingBy( b -> b.getCList().stream().filter( c -> c.getName().equals( "123" ) )
        .collect( groupingBy( c -> c.getName() ) ), toList() ) ) ) );
```

`Collection<List<A>> c = map.values();`
the functions are defined in `java.util.stream.Collectors`

Comment: This method returns:
Map<Map<Map<String, List<C>>, List<B>>, List<A>>